# Does the Goblin Mech always spawn in the west?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I've only played the Throne Room level once, and he spawned in the west. My friend says he spawned in the west for him as well. Two trials is hardly enough to go by, however. If I want to play the level again and set up extra defenses facing west and he comes from the east, I'm going to be in a bad spot.

I ask because the same thing happened to me with the ogre in Foundries and Forges. He always moved and attacked the crystal from the east until I set up all my defenses once facing east, and then he moved to the south entrance instead.

Comment: I do believe they are static, as all my runs through the Throne Room, he has spawned on the west side. However, I'm not 100% sure of it.

Comment: yea, I'm not 100% sure either, but all the bosses seems to spawn in a static spot.

Comment: also, I'm 100% sure that ogre spawns are random for most maps.  When you see a ogre spawn not associated with a door, then it can potentially come out of any door.  The only time I see that ogre spawns always come out of one door is the summit map where they always come out of the south door.

Comment: I do believe it's class specific (this is the same as demon lord: he'll give you a "soul focuser" if you play as the huntress).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the multiple times my friends and I have run this level 20+ (we've been farming it for mana and a better version of the weapon he gives). He has always spawned from that side.

Comment: A lot of people are confirming that they've only ever seen him on the west, so I'm going to believe that's true until I hear different.

Comment: what weapon does he give?  I've only fought him once so I forgot what he dropped.

Comment: I didn't pay attention to what my friends get, but they're class specific. I play a huntress so it's an electrical based gun that does an area of effect explosion when it hits a target or goes a certain range. Really good for groups of monsters.

Comment: I don't believe it's class specific - I think the drop is always the same weapon (though with varying stats).  IIRC this boss gives every player some sort of chainsaw sword for the monk.

Comment: I've never gotten the chainsaw sword on my huntress, always gotten the gun with different stats.

Comment: @BlueRaja boss drops should be class specific, but challenge completion items are not.  Its good to know he gives the aoe weapon, been looking for one for my huntress.